# Multiple cameras make bad performance on mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine

When i add new base camera even though it doesn't display anything my fps on mobile decrease approximately on 10 points. Is new camera on scene so expensive by performance for mobile? I use URP. How can I increase my fps if need six base cameras at time for different render textures?

Comment: A render texture output is still an output - Unity still has to do all the occlusion culling, lighting, etc. to render the scene from that camera's point of view. The way to save time is to not do the rendering. Replace the render textures with static images, turn the cameras off when that render texture can't be seen, etc.

Comment: Note : Camera rendering to the screen and cameras rendering to textures do the same work. What I mean is that even if a camera doesn't *display* anything, it still computes.

Comment: Yep, I mean i add new camera without output render texture and it decrease fps. But I need have six cameras with output render texture for 3d heroes at the same time. Problem is need more then one camera at the time and I cant disable them

Comment: Why are you adding cameras that don't have a display or render texture? Why can't you disable them? Are you *positive* that they're not still setup to render to the screen? What do you have under the `Normalized View Port Rect` settings for the camera? `[0, 0, 1, 1]` is still rendering to your screen even if you can't see it.

Comment: I added cameras to see if it affects performance while looking for the reason why the low fps. In the normal case, I have six cameras with a render output texture. It has poor performance, and I found that the camera without anything reduces fps a lot, but I don’t understand why, because it only renders a black background

Comment: @ArtemVolkov Have you found a solution? I have multiple cameras with its render textures to show animated avatars of the characters in UI layer but also have low fps on mobile.